# Video players stopped responding to media keys

Tags: windows-10, video-playback

Since a couple weeks ago, most nice video players have stopped responding to the keyboard media keys **when out of focus**. I've tried VLC, MPC-HC and PotPlayer.

It used to work before, and it continues working for chrome and my audio player.

It will just no longer work for any of the video players.

Before it used to be that whatever application that could respond was focused last, that's where the media keys worked.

Now, in the apps it does work - music player and chrome, it triggers both, regardless of which one was focused before.

**No, closing chrome does not work.**

Nothing on the system's changed really, apart from windows updates. I'm not sure what's going on. Has anyone else experienced similar behaviour? Whats the cause? Any fixes?

I'm on Windows10 v1903 and when I say updates I *don't mean major OS updates*.

Comment: In the Services applet, try to restart the "Human Interface Device Service".

Comment: Doesn't that also imply that a restart of the computer would fix things as well? Which I have done no less than a dozen times since it stopped working. But it doesn't. Also restarting the service does not help.